# Finding all pairs of integers satisfying gcd(a,b) = 6 and lcm(a,b)=540

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, least-common-multiple

Given that 
$$a\cdot b=gcd(a,b)\cdot lcm(a,b)$$

How can we find all the integer solutions $(a,b)$ if $gcd(a,b)=6$ and $lcm(a,b)=540$?

The first thing I did was factorizing using the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

$$a\cdot b=gcd(a,b)\cdot lcm(a,b)=6\cdot540=2^3\cdot3^4\cdot5$$

I also know that 
$$gcd(a,b)=p_1^{min(a_1,b_1)}\cdot p_2^{min(a_2,b_2)}\dots p_n^{min(a_n,b_n)}$$ 
$$lcm(a,b)=p_1^{max(a_1,b_1)}\cdot p_2^{max(a_2,b_2)}\dots p_n^{max(a_n,b_n)}$$
where $a_1\dots a_n$ and $b_1\dots b_n$ are the exponents in the factorization of $a$ and $b$ respectively.

From there I am not sure where to go to obtain all the possible integers $a$ and $b$.

There is already a similar question on Mathematics SE, however the accepted solution is simply a hint towards the correct procedure to do it, while this question already acknowledged that hint.

Answer (score 1):

HInt:

WLOG $$\dfrac aA=\dfrac bB=6\implies(A,B)=1$$

lcm$(a,b)=6AB=540\implies AB=90=2\cdot3^2\cdot5$ with  $(A,B)=1$

WLOG $A<B\implies90= AB>A^2\implies A<10\iff1\le A\le9$